# Why Does The Default Encoding on XmlReader Behave Differently From XmlTextReader's Default Encoding?

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding

I have an XML file that is ACII encoded.

I have tried reading it using two different Microsoft XmlReader implementations:

1. `XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(fileImport.FileContent, true));`
2. `new XmlTextReader(fileImport.FileContent)`

The first one, XmlReader.Create, which uses StreamReader for its Encoding, works great.

The second one, new XmlTextReader, throws an XmlException with the Message 'Invalid character in the given encoding.'

If you read the MSDN documentation for both of these they are both supposed to detect Encoding from the byte order marks and if that fails fall back to UTF-8.

`XmlTextReader`[[msdn]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.encoding.aspx)
[image: XmlTextReader.Encoding property]

`StreamReader`[[msdn]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb.aspx)
[image: StreamReader constructor]

So, why does XmlTextReader fail, with invalid encoding, while StreamReader doesn't, when the documentation says both implementations, by default, handle encoding identically?

Answer (score 5):

They work the same way, but you're not using them the same way... In the first case you're passing a `StreamReader` as the parameter, and in the second you're passing the file location.

When you create an `XmlReader` on a `TextReader` (such as `StreamReader`), it always uses the encoding of the `TextReader` (ignoring the value of the encoding attribute in the XML declaration). When you just pass a path or a stream, it uses the encoding attribute in the XML declaration.

In your case, I suspect the declared encoding doesn't match the actual encoding of the file. I was able to reproduce your problem by creating an XML file that declares its encoding as UTF-8, but is actually encoded as ANSI. If the file contains non-ASCII characters, I get the same error. But if I fix the encoding in the XML declaration, it works fine...

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas. Good thinking on the declared encoding. I'll double check that when I get back into the office on Monday.

Comment: Hmmm... There isn't an encoding attribute defined on the root node. I'm not sure what XmlTextReader is doing to determine the encoding, but I'm going to run with the StreamReader implementation. If it breaks again maybe it'll be more obvious what the problem is. Thanks.